# where is the error in Pandas crosstab query

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, crosstab

I have Python function that includes a `crosstab` query but the system crashes and display the following error:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

DF SAMPLE:

[image]

the expected result:

```
event_type      watch movie stay at home swimming   camping  meeting
event_location
loc1            0              65           0       254      13
loc2           60              0           125      19
loc3          518              3           705      87
loc4          721              11          318      147
loc5            0             103            0      214      17
```

**during the debug it shows that the `item1`, `item2` are assigned correctly.**

## code:

```
def event_loc(self,df,items):
    for item in items:
        item1 = items[0]
        item2 = items[1]
    df_event_loc_crosstab = pd.crosstab(item1, item2)
    print(df_event_loc_crosstab)
```

Comment: Which line gave the error?

Comment: this line `df_event_loc_crosstab = pd.crosstab(item1, item2)`

Comment: What is item1 and item 2 in the table you posted?

Comment: i ask another question more detailed about the error  this is the link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63899636/how-to-write-a-crosstab-query-in-pandas-and-python-with-visualization]

Comment: item1 = event_type
item2=event_location

Answer (score 0):

Crosstab should pass an index first:

```
df = df.set_index('event_type ')    
df_event_loc_crosstab = pd.crosstab(event_type , event_location)
```

Comment: ok i added the index   it display the following error:
`df_event_loc_crosstab = pd.crosstab(item1,item2,index=[0])
TypeError: crosstab() got multiple values for argument 'index'`

Comment: One column should be the index, e.g. item1 and the second should be a regular column. drop "index=[0]"

Comment: i tried your answer  this but still the same error: `df_event_mohafazat_crosstab = pd.crosstab(item1,item2,index=item1)`  but still the same error

Comment: Please post sample of the DFs

Comment: i tried your answer it display now another error:

code: `def event_mouhafaza(self,df,items):
        
        for item in items:
            item1 = items[0]
            item2 = items[1]
        
        df = df.set_index(item1)    
        df_event_mohafazat_crosstab = pd.crosstab(item1,item2)
        print(df_event_mohafazat_crosstab)`

error:  `raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221509/discussion-between-gtomer-and-user1748102).

Comment: sorry for the late reply but we had connection problem in my country and now its back